# iOS Hyper Sync More Than One-toMany Relationsship to the Same Object

Tags: json, swift, core-data

I am making an app that connects to the [TMDB API](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api).

I use [Hyper Sync](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Sync) to persist JSON to Core Data with the following code:

```
                let completion = { (error: NSError?) in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.backdropData = [[String: AnyObject]]()
                        for image in movie.backdrops!.allObjects as! [Image] {
                            var data = [String: AnyObject]()
                            data[ThumbnailTableViewCell.Keys.ID] = image.filePath as String!
                            data[ThumbnailTableViewCell.Keys.OID] = image.objectID

                            if let filePath = image.filePath {
                                let url = "\(Constants.TMDB.ImageURL)/\(Constants.TMDB.BackdropSizes[0])\(filePath)"
                                data[ThumbnailTableViewCell.Keys.URL] = url
                            }

                            self.backdropData!.append(data)
                        }

                        self.posterData = [[String: AnyObject]]()
                        for image in movie.posters!.allObjects as! [Image] {
                            var data = [String: AnyObject]()
                            data[ThumbnailTableViewCell.Keys.ID] = image.filePath as String!
                            data[ThumbnailTableViewCell.Keys.OID] = image.objectID

                            if let filePath = image.filePath {
                                let url = "\(Constants.TMDB.ImageURL)/\(Constants.TMDB.BackdropSizes[0])\(filePath)"
                                data[ThumbnailTableViewCell.Keys.URL] = url
                            }

                            self.posterData!.append(data)
                        }

                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }

                var data = [[String: AnyObject]]()
                data.append(["id": movie.movieID!.integerValue,
                             "backdrops": backdrops,
                             "posters": posters])
                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "movieID=%@ ", movie.movieID!)
                Sync.changes(data, inEntityNamed: "Movie", predicate: predicate, dataStack: appDelegate.dataStack, completion: completion)
```

When Sync finished saving the JSON data, the `backdrops` are deleted and only the `posters` are saved in Core Data. This is not the behavior I wanted. I also want to save the `backdrops` in Core Data. Any way to fix this?

Here is the screenshot of my Core Data model:

[image]

For full source code, here is the link to my Github project:

[Cineko](https://github.com/jovito-royeca/Cineko)

Comment: What do you mean they're deleted? Existing objects are deleted? New lay added objects from JSON are just not saved? Not clear what you're saying. What deletes them?

Comment: The `backdrops` objects are inserted in Core Data then they are deleted when the `posters` are inserted. This happens during `Sync.changes...` method is executed.

Comment: are you using the latest version from github? there was a bug with multiple relationships between the same 2 entities...

Comment: I updated Sync using Cocoapods. Still the same error with multiple relationships on the same entity.

Comment: you'll need to dig in and take a look what's causing the deletion then

Comment: Hi @jovit.royeca, I maintain the Sync repo. I'm sorry that you didn't got this working. I wish I had seen this before.